# How to count the frequency of a date in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to count the frequency of dates matching in a data frame.

```
df1 <- data.frame(c('1991-01-09', '1991-01-11', '1991-02-17'))
df2 <- data.frame(c('1991-01-09', '1991-01-09', '1991-02-17'))
```

The result would be the following:

```
Date         Freq
1991-01-09    2
1991-01-11    0
1991-02-17    1
```

Comment: Please try to provide real, usable data. Your data here has no names (so bad names will be chosen/assigned by R), and your `df2` is a syntax error by missing a closing quote `'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```r
df1$count <- rowSums(outer(df1$d, df2$d, `==`))
df1
#            d count
# 1 1991-01-09     2
# 2 1991-01-11     0
# 3 1991-02-17     1
```

---

Data

```r
df1 <- structure(list(d = c("1991-01-09", "1991-01-11", "1991-02-17")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
df2 <- structure(list(d = c("1991-01-09", "1991-01-09", "1991-02-17")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sapply` :

```
stack(sapply(df1$col1, function(x) sum(df2$col2 == x)))

#  values        ind
#1      2 1991-01-09
#2      0 1991-01-11
#3      1 1991-02-17
```

Answer (score 0):

or you could use purrr::map_dbl()

```
data.frame("Date" = df1[, 1],
           "Freq" = purrr::map_dbl(df1[, 1], ~sum(.x == df2[, 1]))
           )

        Date Freq
1 1991-01-09    2
2 1991-01-11    0
3 1991-02-17    1
```